# installing imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I am unable to complete the installation of Imagemagick in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Long story short, I have three packages of the latest Imagemagick packages showing in my Synaptic Package manager, including the binary package. Can I run the terminal to complete the installation? Do I need more updates, libraries, dependencies? Please help, it should not be this difficult to install and run Imagemagick.

---

Well, here are three images. Imagemagick2 is largely complete due to the limitations of the screenshot app.

However, the problem remains: even though everything seemed to have gone well, I still can't open and run Imagemagick. It's as if it's there, but I can't operate it.

[image: terminal screenshot]

[image: terminal screenshot]

[image: Synaptic screenshot]

Comment: Please [edit your question above](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1246635/edit) to clearly describe the error message(s) that you have encountered. Exact details and complete output whenever possible -- more detail is better. There are many possible reasons for a failure to install. Without knowing the error (which helps us to understand the reason), we would be guessing blindly.,,and that won't help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can install imagemagick on terminal using this command:

```
sudo apt install -y imagemagick
```

This will prompt you for your password to use root level access. (required for installing packages)

`apt` will automatically resolve and install any necessary dependencies automatically.

You can confirm it is installed with (version may be different):

```
$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2017 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff wmf x xml zlib
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct package of imagemagick to install in Synaptic package manager in Ubuntu 18.04 is marked by the mouse cursor in the below screenshot. The imagemagick-6-common and imagemagick-6.16 packages are dependencies of imagemagick that were installed automatically when the imagemagick package was installed in Ubuntu 18.04.

[image]

Alternatively you can install imagemagick from the terminal with the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install imagemagick
```

Run the command `display` from the terminal to launch the ImageMagick GUI.

[image]